# Error with "sudo apt-get", dictionnary-commons since update to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, apt-get

You can see below the error I encounter.

I did search on Google if the question has already been asked (and answered) but nothing works for me. I can't do sudo apt-get install ...

Thank you in advance if someone can help me with this situation.

Regards,

David

```
david@09:25:47 ~$sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up dictionaries-common (1.20.5) ...
update-default-wordlist: Question empty but elements installed for class "wordlist"
  dictionaries-common/default-wordlist: return code: "0", value: ""
  Choices: , Manual symlink setting
  shared/packages-wordlist: return code: "10" owners/error: "shared/packages-wordlist doesn't exist"
  Installed elements: american (American English), british (British English)

  Please see "/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems", section
  "Debconf database corruption" for recovery info.

update-default-wordlist: Selected wordlist "" 
does not correspond to any installed package in the system
and no alternative wordlist could be selected.
dpkg: error processing package dictionaries-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell:
 aspell depends on dictionaries-common (>> 0.40); however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package aspell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hyphen-en-us:
 hyphen-en-us depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hyphen-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of myspell-en-gb:
 myspell-en-gb depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package myspell-en-gb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of myspell-en-za:
 myspell-en-za depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package myspell-en-za (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mythes-en-us:
 mythes-en-us depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; however:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-updatedicts is not installed.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already


dpkg: error processing package mythes-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 dictionaries-common
 aspell
 hyphen-en-us
 myspell-en-gb
 myspell-en-za
 mythes-en-us
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: this seems to be a question to be asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Try  to install it on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: @Max I am on Ubuntu 14.04 now, I can't revert ? (I don't want to loose my files)

Comment: @Max I don't understand why ? My problem is on ubuntu 14.04. There is no way to solve the problem ?
sudo apt-get update works; upgrade don't ... (and install don't work also)

Comment: @PrR3 I followed your advice and asked my question on SuperUser. Thanks

Comment: Even better would have been to post it on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This helped :

/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems

1) running   `/usr/share/debconf/fix_db.pl` as root

Look which templates were affected

2) `diff -u /var/cache/debconf/config.dat{-old,}    | grep ^[+-]Name`

3) `diff -u /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat{-old,} | grep ^[+-]Name`

4) `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dictionaries-common` 
(This prints that the package is not installed or corrupted.)

5) `sudo apt-get upgrade`

That's it.

Thanks again ;)

Comment: A++  Thanks.  You saved me a rebuild.

Comment: Thanks, It served me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ANY ONE HAVE SELUTION
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
aspell : Depends: dictionaries-common but it is not installed
aspell-en : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.49.2) but it is not installed
hunspell-en-us : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34981875)