# Vagrant file installations fail

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, gtk2

I have the following vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.box_check_update = false
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.memory = "1024"
  vb.cpus = 2
end
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
config.ssh.forward_x11 = true 
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  apt-get update
  apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev gtk2.0 
SHELL
end
```

When I run it, it fails on installations:

```
 ==> default: update-default-wordlist: Question empty but elements installed for class "wordlist"
==> default:   dictionaries-common/default-wordlist: return code: "0", value: ""
==> default:   Choices: , Manual symlink setting
==> default:   shared/packages-wordlist: return code: "10" owners/error: "shared/packages-wordlist doesn't exist"
==> default:   Installed elements: canadian-small (Canadian English -- small)
==> default:   Please see "/usr/share/doc/dictionaries-common/README.problems", section
==> default:   "Debconf database corruption" for recovery info.
==> default: update-default-wordlist: Selected wordlist "" 
==> default: does not correspond to any installed package in the system
==> default: and no alternative wordlist could be selected.
==> default: dpkg: error processing package dictionaries-common (--configure):
==> default:  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
==> default: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell:
==> default:  aspell depends on dictionaries-common (>> 0.40); however:
==> default:   Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
==> default: dpkg: error processing package aspell (--configure):
==> default:  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
==> default: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell-en:
==> default:  aspell-en depends on aspell (>= 0.60.3-2); however:
==> default:   Package aspell is not configured yet.
==> default:  aspell-en depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.49.2); however:
==> default:   Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
==> default: dpkg: error processing package aspell-en (--configure):
==> default:  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
==> default: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hunspell-en-us:
==> default:  hunspell-en-us depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10); however:
==> default:   Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
==> default: dpkg: error processing package hunspell-en-us (--configure):
==> default:  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

When I run the installations manually everything works.

Any idea to why this fails and what can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671727/error-with-sudo-apt-get-dictionnary-commons-since-update-to-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks, tried it doesn't help